# When I clear contents, my dynamic combobox referencing a text box won't clear

Tags: vba, excel

I have a combobox (DescBox1) that references a dynamic range based on the value entered in a text box.

```
Private Sub DescBox1_Change()
    Range("C25").Value = DescBox1.Value
End Sub
```

And

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()        
    Me.DescBox1.RowSource = "CCList1"    
End Sub
```

When we enter a value into a TextBox (ClassCode1) it transfers the value to the active workbook cell B25.

B25 then generates a dynamic list via vlookup which then becomes CCList1.

```
Private Sub ClassCode1_Change()
    Range("B25").Value = ClassCode1.Value
End Sub
```

When I use my clearfields code, it seems to clear all the textboxes first which removes the dynamic lookup reference making it unable to clear the combobox (DescBox1).

```
Private Sub ClearFields_Click()

    Dim ctl As Control

    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If ctl.Name = "ExpModFactor" Then
            Me.ExpModFactor.Value = 1
        Else
            If ctl.Name = "SurchargeTextBox" Then
                Me.SurchargeTextBox.Value = 100
            Else
                Select Case TypeName(ctl)
                    Case "ComboBox"
                        ctl.ListIndex = -1
                    Case "TextBox"
                        ctl.Value = ""
                    Case "CheckBox"
                        ctl.Value = False
                End Select
            End If
        End If
    Next ctl

End Sub
```

Comment: Check to see if your Clear Subroutine does not fire-up the change events in your textboxes and combo-boxes.  In the change event handler, you should validate the value of your combo-box / textbox before making any changes to the worksheet.

Comment: Sorry, I'm unsure of what you mean. I think the clear subroutine does fire-up the change events, but I'm unsure of how to validate that...

Comment: How do you fill up the values of your combo box?

Comment: =OFFSET(Quote!$B$25,COLUMN()-1,) References B25 above. B25 is populated by the userform textbox. Then I use the following formula to pull all matching results to create the CCList1 combobox range =IFERROR(INDEX(FLClassCodes!$C$1:$C$1291,SMALL(IF($A$31=FLClassCodes!$B$1:$B$1291,ROW(FLClassCodes!$B$1:$B$1291)-ROW(FLClassCodes!$B$1)+1),ROW(1:1)))," ") (its an array formula

Comment: Do you need to remove the dynamic lookup references when clearing textboxes?  You could place an if-then clause inside the change event handlers of the textboxes, e.g.  if TextBox.Value = "" then do not update the references, else do the usual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I separated the references so they were clearing in the proper order. I also added a .ClearContents action for clearing the specific field in the worksheet.

```
Private Sub ClearFields_Click()


Dim ctl As Control

For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf ctl Is MSForms.ComboBox Then
        ctl.Text = ""
    End If
Next ctl
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Then
        ctl.Text = ""
    End If
Next ctl
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Then
        ctl.Text = ""
    End If
Next ctl
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf ctl Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
        ctl.Value = False
    End If
Next ctl
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If ctl.Name = "ExpModFactor" Then
        Me.ExpModFactor.Value = 1
    Else
    If ctl.Name = "SurchargeTextBox" Then
        Me.SurchargeTextBox.Value = 100
    End If
    End If
Next ctl


Range("B25:D48").ClearContents
Range("B6").ClearContents
Range("B10").ClearContents
```

Answer (score 0):

Would doing this work?

```
for i = me.controls.count to 1 step -1  
    with me.controls.item(i)
        (your code)
    end with
next
```

Comment: I mean all you put in your originak post, just replacing all "ctl.XXX" with ".XXX" . My idea is to avoid the for each that might be the cause of the problem.